# What is the limit on the number of times you can sign-in, in a given time frame, using Google authentication?

Tags: authentication, google-api, google-oauth

Our product allows customers several different sign-in mechanisms, including Google.  I've been writing test automation using Google authentication and have found that after signing in (roughly) 15 times in 5 minutes, even using the right credentials and MFA code, that the account gets locked with "Too many failed attempts".  I know it hasn't failed because I've watched it sign in correctly.  It usually takes 10 or so minutes and then seems to reset.  But then it happens again and the account is locked for an hour or 2.

I'm sure I'm not the only person automating Google sign in.  Surely there is a way to get around some arbitrary sign in limit for testing.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you performing test automation with Google OAuth? I am not aware of a supported method.

Comment: Automating a web app that uses Google authentication.  Inject username/password/MFA code into page and then sign in.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Google is trying to prevent methods like this. I thought this method had already been locked down.

Comment: So then, how are partners utilizing Google tools and APIs expected to automate their own test scenarios end to end?  And why is there a limit to the number of times you can sign in with valid credentials?  I get trying to block hackers trying different passwords, but why block correct credentials?

Comment: These questions are customer support questions for the vendor. I can only express what I know or my thoughts and opinions. Provide Google with input via feature/support requests. I understand your needs but I also appreciate the necessity of solid security. By allowing you to authenticate over and over - how does Google's AI differentiate this from a hacker launching an attack? Often "ease of use" and "unbreakable security" are opposite ends of convenience, usability and cost.